# Why does ls-l not display locate as a symbolic link?

Tags: ls

I ran the command `ls -l /usr/bin/locate` and from what I have read it is a symbolic link to `slocate`. Attached is a screenshot of what is displayed. As you'll see it is different to the results above it.

Above the result for `ls -l /usr/bin/locate` is a list of symbolic links in the `rc0.d` directory.

Secondly, why does `slocate` have a background color of what seems to be brown.

I have CentOS 5 running.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ls output, `/usr/bin/locate` is not a symbolic link but a regular file. Its orange/brown color is likely due to the setgid bit being set.

Comment: Thanks. I can see that it is not a symbolic link but why is that when other sources cite it as a symbolic link?

Comment: It's just a difference in implementation between distros. The functionality should be the same.

Comment: When you say `implementation` is different, what does this mean exactly?

Comment: That means no standard or technical reason require that command to be a symbolic link so it is up to the Operating System developers to decide.